# Searchable Dynamic Content With AJAX Crawling

Tags: xml, ajax, html, seo

I'm working on a new html5 based portfolio site, so i have a xml file that holds information about projects. for example; project name, date, description, position and previews for each project.

like this;

```
    <project>
                <name>Project Name Here</name>
                <date>September 2011</date>
                <url>www.projecturl.com</url>
                <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Nunc a augue sed ligula tempor facilisis. Curabitur in elit. Etiam dolor wisi, 
    consequat eget, accumsan eu, dignissim nec, est. Morbi sed wisi nec erat feugiat tristique. Fusce tempus.
</description>
                <position>Design</position>
                <previews>
                  <src>prev1.jpg</src>
                  <src>prev2.jpg</src>
                  <src>prev3.jpg</src>
                </previews>
             </project>
```

when site loaded, it gets xml file from server, when i clicked a project from menu, javascript loads information from xml, animates something and brings the information about project.

so my question is
how can i make each project page bookmarkable and crawlable by google?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If SEO is important to you then doing this is a bad idea. Google does offer [crawlable Ajax](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html) but that only helps you with Google. No other search engine can find that content which means you're shutting out 1/3 of the search engine world. Even worse, anyone who does not have JavaScript turned on will also not be able to use your site. This is why [crawlable Ajax is a bad idea](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs).

Comment: Bing is supposed to handle it too: http://searchengineland.com/bing-now-supports-googles-crawlable-ajax-standard-84149

At some point, I hope it will by default, without requiring owners enabling a setting.